# select parent and count of all child class in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following JPA entity structure.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_DETAILS")
class Parent{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parent_details_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parent_details_seq", sequenceName = "PARENT_DETAILS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private long parentId;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_NAME")
    private String parentName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "childPK.parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> child;
    //setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_DETAILS")
public class Child {

    private ChildPK childPK;

    public void setProgramProcessesPK(ChildPK childPK) {
        this.childPK = childPK;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public ChildPK getChildPK() {
        return childPK;
    }

  }


@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Parent parent;

    private long childId;

    @Column(name = "CHILDID")
    public long getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(long childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    public ParentDetails getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

I want to write a JPA query which will return the PARENT_NAME and the count of all children for a given parent_id.

Tthe only solution I can think of is joining and writing a complex criteria query.

I cannot think of a way to get the result using a simple JPA query.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SIZE?  Something like "Select parent.parentName, Size(parent.child) from Parent parent" might work.

Comment: Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select programDetails.state, Size(programDetails.programProcesses) from ProgramDetails programDetails where programDetails.programId=:programId");
        query.setParameter("programId", programId);
        Object result=query.getSingleResult();


i tried this.but this is throwing exception

Comment: sorry for ugly format. Its throwing SQL grammar exception : not a single-group group function

Comment: Could be a JPA provider bug, though it seems very close to the JPA spec example.  Try just "Select Size(programDetails.programProcesses) from ProgramDetails programDetails" and see if you can get the SQL from the original error to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: this worked. may be selecting one non group with grouped is the issue

Comment: I'd suggest checking for bugs on your version, or trying a different provider to see if the query works.  You can try a group by clause, but the spec doesn't state it is needed, and it depends on the SQL that is being generated anyway.  Try to get the SQL that is generated and tweak the JPQL to get what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA Named Query such as this:

```
private static class ParentChildsNumber {
    public String parentName;
    public Integer childsNum;

    public ParentChildsNumber(String parentName, Integer childsNum) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.childsNum = childsNum;
    }
}

@NamedQuery(name="getParentChildsNumberQuery", query="SELECT NEW ParentChildsNumber(p.parentName, SIZE(p.child)) FROM Parent p WHERE p.parentId = :parentId GROUP BY p.parentId, p.parentName")
```

Use it in your code in the following way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="YourPersistentUnit")
private EntityManager em;

em.createNamedQuery("getParentChildsNumberQuery", ParentChildsNumber.class).setParameter("parentId", parentId).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: it throws error : org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity. @Id is missing i suppose. but will it be nice. or should i write two queries one for fetching name and another for count.

Comment: You can definitely stay with one query. A class which you use with NEW clause is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database so I guess you're missing @Id annotation in one of your entity classes.

Comment: I added @id notation on parentName. but now its throwing Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return. But constructor is setting two values only. Is there any other possibility due to which this error occurs.

Comment: I think you should have set of `ProgramProcesses` objects in `Parent` class not set of `Child` objects which you now have. You don't even have `Child` class defined in your code.

Comment: that was a typo. ProgramProcesses is Child class. sorry for that. i tried the same query with createQuery. its throws the sql error : not a single-group group function.

Comment: See edited answer. Look at the added GROUP BY clause in JPQL statement.